# Combine basic auth and redirect in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, basic-authentication

Following situation:

- I wish to redirect all IP adresses (but NOT two fixed ones) if accessing the www.mydomain.tld/SubFolder1/ on my apache to www.mydomain.tld
- Offen basic authentication for the www.mydomain.tld/SubFolder1/ with differen usernames

any idea how to do that?

I tried to use one htaccess file where i added some redirection rules and the basic auth stuff. But I never got the redirection rules to work correctly. Seamed the auth stuff is overwriting the redirection rules. Could that be?

I use the following code for the Authentication

```
AuthName "Restricted"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile //is/htdocs/www/subfolder1/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
require valid-user
```

Comment: Show your present code for using BASIC auth.

Comment: added the codepart for the Basic out I use.

Comment: Should `basic authentication` be shown to all the users before redirection? (including those 2 IPs)?

Comment: No, only the two IPs should see the basic authentication, all other users should be forwarded to the root domain without seeing the authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/SubFolder1/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(192\.168\.0\.10|192\.168\.0\.20)$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mydomain.tld/ [L,R]

SetEnvIf Remote_Addr ^(192\.168\.0\.10|192\.168\.0\.20)$ DOAUTH

AuthName "Restricted"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile //is/htdocs/www/subfolder1/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
require valid-user
Satisfy     any
Order       allow,deny
Allow from  all
Deny from env=DOAUTH
```

`SetEnvIf` is needed because `mod_auth` runs before `mod_rewrite` hence env set by `mod_rewrite` cannot be used `mod_auth`.

Comment: Great, thanks ... By the way, is it possible to use more then one SetEnvIf line, for example if I wish to add 2 additional IPs? this would be handy if I would need to add my home dynamic dial up IP range here. With the pipe I might end up in a very long string

Comment: Oh yes sure you can have as many `SetEnvIf` lines as you want.